# Where is UdpClient.CancelReceive?

Tags: .net, sockets

I'm implementing a simple local-network discovery protocol, so I call UdpClient.Send and then UdpClient.BeginReceive. In case more than one response is pending, I call UdpClient.BeginReceive at the end of the callback. Something like this:

```
UdpClient client = new UdpClient(AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
client.EnableBroadcast = true;
client.Send(request, request.Length, broadcastEndPoint);
client.BeginReceive(Callback, client);
```

...and then in `Callback`:

```
void Callback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    UdpClient client = (UdpClient)ar.AsyncState;
    IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint = null;
    byte[] response = client.EndReceive(ar, ref remoteEndPoint);

    // Do something with response

    client.BeginReceive(Callback, client);
}
```

My problem is that my main loop calls `client.Close` while there's still a receive pending. The receive completes, and then my next call to BeginReceive throws an exception: `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host`

Why doesn't UdpClient have a CancelReceive method? What can I do instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a "isClosing" flag to notify the callback function that the UdpClient is not available anymore is not a proper solution. The callback being executed in a different thread, there's always a chance that the connection is closed after the "isClosing" flag check and before the "BeginReceive" (or "EndReceive") call.

Even though that's not a clean design, Microsoft seems to recommend to just catch the corresponding exceptions to detect that the socket isn't available anymore. That's not documented for "BeginReceive", but that's [documented for the similar function "BeginConnect"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6aeby4wt%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) :

> To cancel a pending call to the BeginConnect() method, close the
>   Socket. When the Close() method is called while an asynchronous
>   operation is in progress, the callback provided to the BeginConnect()
>   method is called. A subsequent call to the EndConnect(IAsyncResult)
>   method will throw an ObjectDisposedException to indicate that the
>   operation has been cancelled.

So, sample code would look like :

```
void Callback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        UdpClient client = (UdpClient)ar.AsyncState;
        IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint = null;
        byte[] response = client.EndReceive(ar, ref remoteEndPoint);

        // Do something with response

        client.BeginReceive(Callback, client);
    }
    catch (SocketException e)
    {
        // Oups, connection was closed
    }
    catch (ObjectDisposedException e)
    {
        // Oups, client was disposed
    }
}
```

Comment: What about:

 UdpClient client = (UdpClient) ar.AsyncState;
if ( client.Client == null ) return;

Answer (score 6):

Instead or to overcome this exception create bool and set it before issuing the close command, use that bool to check in callback

like this

```
bool isClosing=false;
void Callback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    if(isClosing) return;
}
```

set the `bool` `isClosing` before issuing the close command